# Can I camp in the protected areas Þjórsárver and Guðlaugstungur og Álfgeirstungur?

Tags: hiking, camping, iceland

I am investigating the feasibility of a hike looping around Hofsjökull.  The route takes me through the [Þjórsárver](http://www.ust.is/einstaklingar/nattura/fridlyst-svaedi/sudurland/thjorsarver/) and [Guðlaugstungur og Álfgeirstungur](https://protectedplanet.net/346546) protected areas.  The [regulations for Þjórsarver](http://www.ust.is/library/Skrar/Einstaklingar/Fridlyst-svaedi/Auglysingar/thorsarver_507_1987.pdf) and [those for Guðlaugstungur og Álfgeirstungur](http://www.ust.is/library/Skrar/Einstaklingar/Fridlyst-svaedi/Auglysingar/gudlaugstungur_1150_2005.pdf) do not appear to make mention of camping, but Google Translate may fool me here.

Am I permitted to camp in those protected areas?

Naturally, I would practice strict leave no trace and avoid fragile vegetated areas, which is exactly what makes Þjórsárver so unique in the Highlands of Iceland (compare [Þjórsárver photos](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/iceland-ho/sets/72157594472287697/) with neighbouring [Sprengisandur](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Sprengisandur&tbm=isch)!)

Comment: Hi gerrit. I'm way out of my element here and probably can't help you, but I found an important publication entitled [Parks, The International Journal of Protected Areas and Conservation](https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/parks_22.1_-_2016.pdf). Starting on Page 13 is an extensive discussion of Iceland, the development of its protected areas and what it means. It mentions the importance of tourism and also the need to control it to preserve the area, but I didn't see a specific reference to camping. Maybe you can read it more clearly than I could.

Comment: I also found some tourist camping areas in the region, but I don't know if they're in the protected areas. I can provide them if you want. That's an absolutely fascinating region! What a blessing it is to be able to make a trip like that!

Comment: @Sue Yes, it's a blessing!  There are some tourist areas like in Nýidalur and Kerlingarfjöll, as well as a couple of cabins owned by 4x4 clubs, but I'm hiking and the tourist areas are much too far apart to hike from tourist area to tourist area.